# django date filter not working

Tags: python, django

I want to convert django datetime field into date ...i am trying date filter but it does not seem to be working ..may be i am doing something wrong...

```
I want to convert `"April 20, 2013, 6:53 p.m." to "20-April-2013"`

I have tried django template filter {{ lastUsed|date:"d-M-Y"}}
```

but it is not working. I also tried ...including a method in model but it is not working either....

```
def convertLastTestedToDate(self):
    return self.lastTested.date.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M')
```

can some one tell me how to convert django datetime field into date.

Comment: What does `lastUsed` look like in your view (and I assume model)? Can you add your view/model code?

Comment: Model : `lastTested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` in view i am just rendering  JSON data into template and then it lokks like :    `{% for i in couponList %} <span> {{ i.lastTested}}</span> {% endfor %}`

Comment: sorry it is <span>  {{ lastUsed|date:"d-M-Y"}} </span>

Comment: I have added a new method def convertLastTestedToDate(self): return self.lastTested.strftime('%B %d %Y') And it is converting ....datetime field into required format...But thanks for trying to help...

Comment: @user2217267 You should post your solution as an answer so that other users can find your question and solution helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the following to show the full month:

```
{{lastUsed|date:"d-F-Y"}}
```